# Is it possible to handle naming duplictates for teminal points in ARINC-424?

Tags: instrument-procedures, waypoint, arinc-424

In ARINC-424 17 specification, under `7.2.6 Terminal Waypoints` subsection A the "Airport/Heliport or Runway/Helipad related Terminal Waypoints" naming conventions are described. It describes the steps to be taken in order to avoid duplicates.

For example: a final approach fix (FAF in short) on runway 36 for example, will be named `FF36` which works either for "Single Approach Procedure" or approaches that share a "common waypoint". If the common waypoint idea can't be applied, then the second letter becomes the route type described in section 5.7. So the FAF for a `VOR` approach on 36 will be `FV36`, for an `ILS` on 36 `FI36` and so on and so forth.

But here lies the problem (which unfortunately I am currently facing): what if there are more than one approaches of the same type on the same runway that can't share the same points? I have 2 `VOR` approaches where all points IAF, IF, FAF etc. do not coincide. According to the spec:

> waypoint identifiers will be unique only for the airport specified; a waypoint identifier used in a terminal area cannot be repeated in that terminal area

I could get away with it as there are is no parallel runway and I can start adding numbers (eg `FV361`, `FV362` etc.) and it won't make any significant difference as these points will be used for simulation purposes and I have a couple of ways to "cheat". Though knowing what happens in reality will add to the simulation realism.

Comment: Which airport is this?

Comment: @Bianfable it's LGEL but unfortunately I can't provide you with maps as the one of the 2 approaches in question is in military AIP and is not public. The other can be found [here](https://aisgr.hcaa.gr/aipgr_incl_amdt_0622_wef_14jul2022/cd/ais/eaip/pdf/AD%202/AD2-LGEL/AD2-LGEL-IAC-3.pdf) (link will most probably expire in the next AIRAC update). Let me know if you find the one published helpful and I will update the question.

Comment: OK, my navigation data for LGEL shows 3 VOR approaches: VOR Y RWY 36L, VOR A RWY 36L and VOR W RWY 36R. Not sure if any of these is the military procedure you mean. I could write an answer containing the names of the CD and FD waypoints on these procedures. Would that help?

Comment: Duh I forgot. They are doing works and they converted a taxiway to runway and named it 36L. Sure the names for  VOR Y RWY 36L and VOR A RWY 36L will be helpful as long as they don't have coinciding points. I only have VOR Y not VOR A so I can't tell immediately if it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example of LGEL, I found 3 VOR approaches in my navigation database with the following points:

| Approach | Cx Name | Fx Name | Mx Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D36LY | CD3LY | FD3LY | MD3LY |
| D36RW | CD36 | FD36 | MD36 |
| VORA | CD36 | FD36 | MD36 |

As you can see, the VOR W RWY 36 R approach (where you also linked the chart) uses the normal naming convention for a runway 36. The VOR A is the circle to land approach using the same waypoints. The interesting one is the VOR Y RWY 36 L approach, which uses different waypoints. The naming now uses only the first digit of the runway number (3 instead of 36), followed by L for 36L and then the letter of the approach (here Y).

This allowed me to search my navigation database for similarly named waypoints and sure enough I found a good example, where there are 2 approaches to *the same runway* using a different waypoint at **LIRP** (Pisa San Giusto):

| Approach | Cx Name | Fx Name | Mx Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D04LZ | CD0LZ | FD04L | MD04L |
| S04LY | CD0LY | FD04L | MD04L |

As you can see, both approaches use the same final approach fix (Fx) and missed approach fix (Mx), but a *different* final approach course fix (Cx) using the naming convention described above.

The same convention can also be applied when there is no left/right/center. E.g. **EBBR** (Brussels) uses Cx waypoints **CD25Y** and **CD25Z** for runway 25.

My copy of the ARINC 424 standard does not describe this convention, but apparently this is what Jeppesen uses.

Comment: Ah indeed this is ingenious. +1 from me. I hope you don't mind if I wait for 1 day before accepting. I'd like to avoid discouraging someone else from answering, if they have another bit of information to add -though I doubt it :).

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis Sure, no problem. Maybe someone will find where this is actually documented...